# Loop DataColumns in DataRow

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am converting data table content to string, Say the dataset has 12 rows and 8 column.
At the end, the Dict contain 12 rows or 96 columns. what's wrong with my code below, how do I reset the row?

Tia.

```
        Dim ds As DataSet = ClsDB.GetDataSet(sql)

    If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        Dim dict As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Object))
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        Dim i As Integer = 0 

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows 
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(dc.ColumnName, IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), dr.Item(dc.ColumnName), "")))
            Next
            dict.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Object)(i, row))
            i += i 
        Next

        Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict)
    Else
        Return "No Data"
    End If
```

Comment: You should reinitialise `row` for every `dr`, right?

Comment: yah, what a simple careless. Think too much in-the-box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reinitialise `row` for every `dr`, in fact you needn't declare `row` outside the `dr` loop.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim row As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))   // <<-         
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns                 
        row.Add(...
    Next             
    dict.Add(...
Next
```